# How to display 2 interdependent reports in one SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I want to design a report where Report1 has a table1 and column1 of table1, should display the complete detail of that column on OnClick event. can I show 2 linked reports in one report based on the onclick event? if so how?

I tried using Subreport concept but that didn't work. Tried Bookmark but got rejected by the client also tried using go to report option but that open up in either different or same window but replace the existing report and to see your previous report I have to click on go back button. last option which I can think of is combine them in asp.net page.

Comment: You can either go with the subreport option and the go back button or you group your data in your tablix. After grouping you can chose if you want to display (by a toggle button) the detaildata. But this depends on the structure of your data.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate a little more on the first paragraph?  Are you expecting the cells in column 1 to expand and show the detail, or navigate you to another page?  Maybe a mock-up of the what you are looking for visually would help.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, the "go to" options on a textbox forces you to navigate away from the report and into a new report.

As Strawberryshrub mentioned, would a toggle option work for you?  Here is a simple example of that:

> Report Design:

[image: Example Report Design]

> Report Collapsed:

[image: Example Report Collapsed]

> Report Expanded:

[image: Example Report Expanded]